# Angular-chartjs expression/value inside canvas class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm trying to change the class of a canvas using Angular expression but i couldnt find out why i cant.

```
<canvas class="{{graphType}}"
chart-data="mainCtrl.data" 
chart-labels="mainCtrl.labels" 
chart-options="mainCtrl.options">
```

I also tried with `class="{{'graphType'}}"` , `class="'{{graphType}}'"`, `class="graphType"`, `class="mainCtrl.graphType"` and `ng-class="{{graphType}}"` but i couldnt succeeded.
But when i use `class="chart chart-line"` it work just fine.

And on the controller i have:

```
$scope.graphType = 'chart chart-line';
```

I appreciate any help. Here's a example on jsfiddle:

Edit: dependencies fixed but the graph still does not show up.
https://jsfiddle.net/223wtffm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you want to change the type of the chart using angular-chart from line to pie etc. The angular-chart provides dynamically changing chart not based on class but on another attribute `chart-type`.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exck5ya4/) where I am changing the graphtype dynamically using a timeout. Hope it might help

Comment: It's not class issue, its library issue.

Comment: Oh i didn't realize there's a lot of dependency issues going on, i'm gonna update the question. Also the graph on my code works fine if i just use class="chat chart-line". And what do you mean by library issues? sorry i'm quite beginner to angular.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working jsfiddle that changes the chart type. Angular-chart.js is not watching class name for re-rendering the graph canvas instead it listens on another attribute ```chart-type```

Comment: Just a little detail to complement. Why i cant change the chart-type directly writing the type there? like: chart-type="line" or chart-type="bar" ? it only work when i use the $scope to do it

Comment: That's how the library might have been designed. I am not sure. Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/634)

Answer (score 0):

Your js fiddle says:

```
var vm = this;
```

but it should be:

```
var vm = $scope;
```

Your jsfiddle works if you change this because putting the below styles in the css shows that the class name has been applied

```
.chart{
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.chart-line{
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Yes i corrected and updated the jsfiddle. But its still not working.

Comment: That's weird, with the css applied i can see the canvas, but the graph itself does not show up.